# How can I use tsx with snabbdom-jsx (not React)?

Tags: typescript, jsx

All the documentation I found explains how to use TypeScript with React, but I am interested in using it along with snabbdom-jsx ? Any idea on how to configure tsconfig for this to work ?

From **[snabbdom-jsx](https://github.com/yelouafi/snabbdom-jsx)** docs on using babel:

> The /** @jsx html */ pragma at the top tells Babel to use the html function instead of the React.createElement default. The html function takes arguments passed from Babel and generates virtual nodes as expected by Snabbdom's patch function.

Is there something equivalent to this `@jsx html` configuration for TypeScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The /** @jsx html */ pragma at the top tells Babel to use the html function instead of the React.createElement
>
> Is there something equivalent to this @jsx html configuration for TypeScript ?

Yes. Its `reactNamespace`. E.g. `reactNamespace foo` and then you get `foo.createElement`. You can use this to create `foo.createElement = someOhterLibMethod` to make it work with whatever.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/jsx/tsx.html

Also supported in [alm](https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/f8d597374437cbc5911f0cabe26124a29d8eaa11/src/server/workers/lang/core/tsconfig.ts#L72)

Answer (score 1):

This is my working gulp file who transforms .tsx to snabbdom virtual dom.

Skip the /** @jsx html */ pragma and import {html} who isn't working in TypeScript 2.

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: [paths.tsadmin],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {},
        plugin: [tsify]
    })
        .transform('babelify', {
            extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"]
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + '/js'));
});
```

And the .babelrc file.

```
{
            "presets": [
                "es2015"
            ],
            "plugins": [
                "syntax-jsx",
                [
                    "transform-react-jsx",
                    {
                        "pragma": "bsj.html"
                    }
                ],
                [
                    "jsx-pragmatic",
                    {
                        "module": "snabbdom-jsx",
                        "import": "bsj"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
```